# Magento 1 - how to check if product page is opened from search page results?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalogsearch

I've working on analytics.
I am having some difficulty to have an idea
if product is opened from search page or not.
How can i determine it ?

Thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');` to know from which page request came.

Comment: can you please add full syntax or boilerplate code, how to get it ?

Comment: Great , let me check it quickly.

Comment: I am not able to upvote right now , but will do it , correct answer for the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please upvote if the answer is correct.

Comment: I am not able to upvote right now , but will do it , correct answer for the question. Thanks

Comment: Sanjib can you please initiate a chat group , want to know your opinion on magento , if you don't mind.